# Blackberry - Is it possible to ignore doing 'Request Signatures' every time?

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-storm

I am developing Blackberry application. Every time when i want to test my app program changes on the Blackberry storm device, i need do 'Request Signatures' every time. Can't we ignore doing it every time?

Thanks.

Comment: Blackberry has a very secured environment for testing applications on device. Unless and until you sign your application, it cannot be deployed on handset. No alternative. Otherwise,it gives message as "Application trying to access secure ApI"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own build scripts that sign the application using the command line tool as part of the build script.

Here is how to [run the signing tool from command line](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800989/How_To_-_Use_the_SignatureTool_from_a_command_line.html?nodeid=800994&vernum=0)

Answer (score 3):

Just an additional information:

- [A60 - How And When To Sign - For BlackBerry SmartPhones - By Andre Fabris](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A60_How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf)
- [Automated Blackberry sign tool (Mac, Linux & Windows)](http://blog.lightvoid.net/2008/04/28/automated-blackberry-sign-tool-mac-linux-windows/)
- [BlackBerry Development with Ant & Eclipse](http://www.slashdev.ca/2007/05/30/blackberry-development-with-ant-eclipse/)
- [BB Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/)